# django add html code every 4 iterations

Tags: html, django

I am using django to build my site, and i am adding html code dynamically this way:

```
{% for ad in ads_search %}
    <li class="span3" id="list-all">
        <a href="#" class="thumb">
           <div id="most-viewed">
           <div class="tag" id="tag-cinema"></div>
               <img src="{{ad.image_url}}" alt="">
       <p>{{ad.name}}</p>
       <div class="barra-pequena"></div>
       <ul class=" unstyled">
       <li><div class="local"><p>{{ad.local}}</p></div></li>
       <li class="pull-right"><div class="price"><h5> {{ad.price}} </h5></div></li>
       <li><div class="clock"><p>Horário</p></div></li>
       </ul>
     </div>
     </a>                   
    </li>
    {% endfor %}
```

but i want to add :

```
<ul class="inline">
```

every four ads's. How can i do it?

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty, use [the `cycle` tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#cycle):

```
<ul class="{% cycle "" "" "" "inline" %}">
```

Answer (score 0):

Already got my answer, had to use:

```
{% forloop.counter == 4 %}
```

[EDIT]: for this specific situation it is better to use:

{% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:"4" %}

Comment: that will only work for loops with less then 8 entries, i.e. it will only get the first iteration, not _every_ iteration